# Failed to listTables: Missing authentication for Google BigTable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I haven't been able to find much on the web about this problem but...

I am setting up a fresh BigTable cluster on Googles Cloud services. I've gone through the whole process you do with most Google APIs (create service account, know your project ID, authing with the gcloud tool, Google enviornment variable set, etc.).

I am having a problem though after going through the setup. I get this error I can't find anything on web on that says:

```
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: 
    NOT_FOUND: Error listing tables for cluster projects/bigtable-1127/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/bigdatastats : Failed to read Tables in cluster: bigdatastats
```

---

Here is the complete print that includes the error..note that I get the same error when trying to create a table as well:

```
 ./bin/hbase com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CheckConfig
User Agent: bigtable-hbase-1.0-0.2.1
Project ID: bigtable-1127
Cluster Id: bigdatastats
ZoneId: us-central1-c
Cluster admin host: bigtableclusteradmin.googleapis.com
Table admin host: bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com
Data host: bigtable.googleapis.com
Attempting credential refresh...
HBase Connection Class = com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection (OK)
Opening table admin connection...
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/Michael/bigtable/hbase-1.0.1.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2015-11-12 01:30:31,552 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-11-12 01:30:32,619 INFO  [main] grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId bigtable-1127, zoneId us-central1-c, clusterId bigdatastats, on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
Tables in cluster bigdatastats:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to listTables
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.requestTableList(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.listTableNames(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:208)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CheckConfig.main(CheckConfig.java:99)
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Error listing tables for cluster projects/bigtable-1127/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/bigdatastats : Failed to read Tables in cluster: bigdatastats
    at io.grpc.stub.Calls.getUnchecked(Calls.java:117)
    at io.grpc.stub.Calls.blockingUnaryCall(Calls.java:129)
    at com.google.bigtable.admin.table.v1.BigtableTableServiceGrpc$BigtableTableServiceBlockingStub.listTables(BigtableTableServiceGrpc.java:338)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableTableAdminGrpcClient.listTables(BigtableTableAdminGrpcClient.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.requestTableList(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:219)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Error listing tables for cluster projects/bigtable-1127/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/bigdatastats : Failed to read Tables in cluster: bigdatastats
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:428)
    at io.grpc.stub.Calls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(Calls.java:324)
    at io.grpc.ChannelImpl$CallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.run(ChannelImpl.java:402)
    at io.grpc.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It would be amazing if someone could help with this. I am not sure what to do and I can't find anything out there. Obviously its around authentication, my key file is fresh and in the right place, ive ran the gcloud auth and Im not sure what else to check.

Please let me know if I can provide anymore information to help answer.

Comment: Have you downloaded the quickstart? https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-shell-quickstart  it should work on both Linux and Mac.  Just set GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS to point to the .json credentials.  I'm curious what's happening in your "Attempting credential refresh".

Comment: I think I am getting closer...I did have the quickstart installed from a previous projects which is probably what my problem is. I enabled full debugging on the last line of the quickstart.sh file and it looks like an old project I specified is the issue: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default-cli) on project testing:  <<< Any idea where I change this project "testing"

Comment: the NOT_FOUND seems to indicate that the projects/bigtable-1127/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/bigdatastats Cluster doesn't exist.  Could there possibly be a typo in the project or cluster name?

Comment: followed by:  gcloud config set project  <blah>

Comment: @lcm — have you resolved your issue or are you still having trouble connecting to Bigtable?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this was unlikely to have been an authentication issue.

You would receive NOT_FOUND as an error if the resource you are trying to query does not exist in your project. So it's likely that you wanted to switch your default project using `gcloud config set project` as recommended by Les.